# Windows public ssh key on remote linux

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, key

I have public ssh key created on Windows 7 and I want to install it on remote Debian. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question here is off-topic and will probably be moved to http://serverfault.com.

However, copy your public key to the remote debian system with `scp` (I don't have a Windows machine, so I will give you Linux instruction, try to understand them and modify them according to your operative system):

`scp /path/to/public/key.pub user@debian-server:~/.ssh/key.pub`

It will ask your password to log in, then it will copy the key and log out.
Log in again in your machine with ssh and do the following:

```
ssh user@debian-server
chmod 700 .ssh
cd .ssh
cat key.pub >> authorized_keys
chmod 600 authorized_keys
exit
```

Now, you should be able to log in remotely without issuing your password, providing that RSA authentication method is enabled in sshd_config on the debian server.

Note: the `chmod` part is not worldwide required, but sometimes wrong permission on files and folder will prevent you to correctly login.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store your public key into `.ssh/authorized_keys` on your debian machine.

You will find the .ssh folder in your home directory if `openssh-server` is installed.

Comment: So in this file I have: "ssh-rsa some chars/others chars/other chars/other chars/other chars/other chars//other chars ab@cdefghijk". Where should I put my key? Why some time there is one slash and last time there are two?

Comment: the number of slashes doesn't matter. Just put the new key to the end of your file (new line).